# Transfer 100 Excel files to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I use PHP dbase extention to read dbase files and upload them into MySQP.

My Code:

```
 if(dbase_open($FileDir,0)){

                    $dbOpen = dbase_open($FileDir,0);
                    $records = dbase_numrecords($dbOpen);

                    $qry = "";
                    $qry = "INSERT INTO ".$Table." (`SCADA`, `Date`, `PlantNo`, `State`, `SubState`, `Frequency`) VALUES ";

                    for ($i=1; $i<=$records; $i++){

                        $rows = dbase_get_record_with_names($dbOpen,$i);
                        $qry .= '('.$SCADA.','.$rows['Date'].','.$rows['PlantNo'].','.$rows['State'].','.$rows['SubState'].','.$rows['Frequency'].'),';

                    }

                    $qry = substr($qry, 0, -1);
                    $Insert = $conn -> prepare($qry);
                    $Insert -> execute();
```

Now I have to do the same but with xls files! I know that I can convert them into csv and import them via PHP, but I have 100 xls files... How can I transfer them to MySQL? Ant idea?

Comment: By using [phpexcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)?

Comment: I use phpexcel plugin for read excel files and insert data into mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Direct import from Excel to MySQL will not be possible without a third party proprietary product, that you would need to buy like - dbForge Studio or something (I have not tried this one, so I cant even recommend it). Tool called phpmyadmin used to have this functionality, but its depreciated since version  3.4.5, so if you install an old one it might be an option for you. That really depends on several factors.

For a general start, ofcourse, you should make sure that the file you want to import has the same columns, and column order as the database where you want to import it into.

If you convert, or export your xls files into CSV (its a seperate story on how to do that and I will not cover here, plenty of resources or online converters out there), you can merge all of them either in Excel, or from your console. On all modern operating systems you can just put all files in the same directory, cd or dir into it and run "cat *.csv > merged.csv" which will merge all files into one. (copy /b *.csv merged.csv on windows machines)

Once you have a single merged file you can run php to execute the mysql import - 
"LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/path/to/file/merged.csv' INTO TABLE tablename" (more about it here - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

Ofcourse you can also automate exporting XLS into CSV by using a php library like PHPExcel - https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

Seems you can try use:
1. PHP-EXCEL-READER (http://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/)
2. PHPExcel (https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

As Cninroh suggests, you'll need a proprietary product.  I suggest a product I wrote called [Excel2MySQL](http://www.excel2mysql.net/).  It has a simple user interface for manual imports and it also includes a [command line interface](http://www.excel2mysql.net/cli.html) for automating uploads and can read any excel file directly.  No need to export as a csv file.  The Excel sheetnames define the destination MySQL table name.  The table can be automatically created or simply appended to.  All fields can also be automatically optimized to the proper MySQL type. The program is free to try, so you can verify if it will work for you.

```
-h, --help, display help message and exit
-f file, Excel file to convert (include full path) (REQUIRED)
-s sheet, Excel sheet to convert (omit to convert all)
-z host, mysql server hostname or IP address (omit will default to localhost)
-d database, mysql database name (REQUIRED)
-u user, mysql user name (REQUIRED)
-p password, mysql password
-x port, mysql port number (omit will default to 3306)
-r, replace existing table (omit to append to existing table)
-n, first row is not a header (omit to indicate first row contains header)
-a, allow spaces in table & field names (omit to change spaces to underscores)
-m, use myisam database storage engine (omit to use innodb)
-k, keep blank rows & columns (omit to remove)
-c, Unmerge merged cells
-v, define all fields as varchar type on tables (omit to optimize field types)
```

Here is an example command line to upload an excel file and all it's sheets to tables:

```
excel2mysqlCLI.exe -f "c:\my excel.xls" -d mydb -u myid -p mypass
```